# Xcode Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Developing an app which converts shoe sizes. But I am getting this error on launch.

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mensShoeSizeTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func convertButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
       let sizeFromTextField = mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.text
       let numberFromTextField = Int(sizeFromTextField!)
       var integerFromTextField = numberFromTextField!
       let conversionConstant = 30
       integerFromTextField += conversionConstant
       mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.hidden = false
       let stringWithUpdatedShoeSize = "\(integerFromTextField)"
       mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.text = stringWithUpdatedShoeSize
    }
}
```

Comment: What's is the complete error ?

Comment: 2016-03-18 21:48:15.409 BetterShoeConverter[4841:1362844] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1336863583_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Which line is the error? It probably occurs on either `let numberFromTextField = ...` or `var integerFromTextField = ...` because those two lines unwrap optionals, as stated in the error. Check to see if `sizeFromTextField` is a non-nil value.

Answer (score 1):

Both errors are different.
1. Regarding keyboard not found, it is warning because of you might hiding keyboard from simulator settings.
Try this to flush warning

```
iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard
```

2. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
   This is causing because somewhere in your code you are not properly unwrapping the optionals.
   One thing I can see from your code is you are not unwrapping this:

   let numberFromTextField = Int(sizeFromTextField!)

Try it like this:

```
        let sizeFromTextField = mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.text
        if let numberFromTextField = Int(sizeFromTextField!) {
            var integerFromTextField = numberFromTextField
            let conversionConstant = 30
            integerFromTextField += conversionConstant
            mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.hidden = false
            let stringWithUpdatedShoeSize = "\(integerFromTextField)"
            mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.text = stringWithUpdatedShoeSize

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` then it is likely to be caused by one of the following lines:

```
let numberFromTextField = Int(sizeFromTextField!)
var integerFromTextField = numberFromTextField!
```

Here you are force unwrapping the optional values, so you will get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` if they are `nil`. This is particularly problematic for parsing a `String` as an `Int` where `Int(string)` returns nil if it couldn't parse the String as a number.

You should change your code to elegantly handle the nil values:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var mensShoeSizeTextField: UITextField?

    @IBOutlet var mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel: UILabel?

    @IBAction func convertButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if let sizeFromTextField = mensShoeSizeTextField?.text, let mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel = mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel, let integerFromTextField = Int(sizeFromTextField) {
            let conversionConstant = 30
            let convertedIntegerFromTextField = integerFromTextField + conversionConstant
            mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.hidden = false
            let stringWithUpdatedShoeSize = "\(convertedIntegerFromTextField)"
            mensConvertedShoeSizeLabel.text = stringWithUpdatedShoeSize
        }
    }
}
```